# How to get values for X when it gets values between y and z?

Tags: r

I'm trying to drive command where i would get values from X which are between variables y and z. I didn't find it from my R quide, does anyone remember?
like x[y,z]

I've already tried cut(), between, min(y) max(z), nothing of these haven't worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What class of object is X? Is it a daframe, a vector? When you say variables y and x, do you mean values y and z? Please see how to make a good question in R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `x[x > y & x < z]`.

If you use data.table, it comes with a nice `%between%` operator and `between()` function so you can write `x[x %between% c(y, z)]` if `y` and `z` are atomic vectors, or `x[between(x, y, z)]` if they are vector of the same length as `x`.

dplyr has also a `betweeen()` function.

Comment: You're welcome :) You can mark this or other answers as correct so that your question is shown as "answered" .

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer:

```
x <- 1:10
x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
y <- 3
z <- 7
x[x>=y & x <=z]
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```